# How to use mysql in gevent based programs in python?

Tags: python, mysql, gevent

I have found that ultramysql meets my requirement. But it has no document, and no windows binary package.

I have a program heavy on internet downloads and mysql inserts. So I use gevent to solve the multi-download-tasks problem. After I downloaded the web pages, and parsed the web pages, I get to insert the data into mysql.

Is monkey.patch_all() make mysql operations async?

Can anyone show me a correct way to go.

Comment: I have found no answer. Now I created a simple multi-threaded http server as a sql layer for gevent programs and interact with mysql as result as josn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres may be better suited due to its asynchronous capabilities

Answer (score 1):

I think one solution is use pymysql. Since pymysql use python socket, after monkey patch, should be work with gevent.